# После клика на ссылку, при загрузке страницы сохранить прежние настройки. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.
У меня есть боковое меню и при клике оно должно быть таким
[image: 1]

Т.е. Меню подкатегории должно оставаться открытым, плюс подчеркивать текущий раздел.

Прописал так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.submenu-item').on('click', function(){
            $(this).css("text-decoration","underline");
            $(this).parent('.submenu').css('display','block');
        })  
    });
```

Но после загрузки страницы все естественно схлопывается.

[image: 1]

Как правильно прописать, чтобы после загрузки этой страницы, которую нажали, подгрузило те свойства стилей, которые я прописал?

Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: надо сохронять позицию в localStorage

Comment: Хорошо, а как именно по селектору "this"?

Comment: попробуйте `$(this).index()`, а потом выташить эту позицию

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться